# Error on add to source control - Unable to transfer a file: error detected by clearcase subsystem

Tags: clearcase

We are setting up new servers at CC 8.1.1.11 and going through basic tests.

From a CC Explorer client we try and add a simple .txt file to source control and get the error

```
Error adding "path to filename.txt" to source control Unable to transfer file : 
error detected by Clearcase Subsystem.
```

Selecting Ok on the error pop-up we can then see the "Green Tick" against the file showing it checked out but when we try to check in we get the same error.

In the mvfs log on the client machine we see the following

```
Fetch cleartext view=viewname vob=\vobname dbid=0x43 - I/O error
See view log on  view server for more info.
```

View Log on view Server -

```
Error: view_server.exe error unable to construct cleartext for object "0x43" in vob "path to vob" 
Error detected by clearcase subsystem
Error unable to transfer a file.
```

Client machine and view server are windows. Vob server aix
No significant errors when running ClearCase doctor.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: What is the config spec of your view?

Comment: I'm using a dynamic view with cs of element * CHECKEDOUT element * /main/LATEST. so just the standard basic config spec. I'll check through the other points and update. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All, Thanks both for the input. The issue resolution was -

- samba was missing username mapping to map the albd account to the vob owner account.
- In smb.conf vobstore section was updated to have the write list group defined with an @ so that the group did not need to be the users Primary Group.
- Getting Samba and nmbd properly stopped and started not just restarted.
- Disabling CCFS on both the client and view server through the clearcase control panel, then stopping and restarting Clearcase "As Administrator" not just as an account with admin permissions.

Comment: Good feedback, thank you. +1 Don't forget: you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014278684#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014287254)

> The usual reason is access rights in the cleartext pool (down from the 'c' directory in the vob storage).
>
> But I recently got this in conjunction with a clearer report in the `vobrpc` log (I think), for 'group not declared in the vob' (or similar).
>   The user was actually work as root, and his group was '`other`'.
>   Although he was allowed to write to the (local) cleartext pool, the `type_manager` would refuse with this (misleading?) error...

So double-check your `vobrpc` logs, and check your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` (whose group needs to be part of the primary or secondary groups of the Vob involved with those files)

Check also the protections associated with your view:

```
cd /path/to/my/view 
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

Comment: Hi (apologies for formatting) on the vobserver the vobrpc log in empty. On the vob server running credmap my primary groups is "staff" not fg_rat_users" which is our version of ccusers but this is my secondary group. Within the VOB the "c" directory has groups "fg_rat_users". The vob ownership is "fg_rat_users" with secondary of "PG_RAT_USERS" our version of ccadmin. PG_RAT_USERS is also defined as our Clearcase Admin Group

Comment: empty locally or on the ClearCase server? Whenever you check logs on ClearCase, you must do so both locally and on the server.

Comment: vobrpc log in empty when checked also on the view server

Comment: @DBeange And when checked on the Vob server?

Comment: empty on vobserver too.

Comment: on both the windows client and windows view server the CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP is set as fg_rat_users

Comment: @DBeange How about your view properties?

Comment: using cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview for my view it shows, view owner as my id with RWX, group fg_rat_users with RWX, other r-x

Comment: OK. All checks are looking good, so I am not sure about the root cause right now...

Comment: Could it be that on the vob server my primary group is not fg_rat_users? Or as long as it's one of my groups there shouldnt be an issue whether it's primary or not?

Comment: @DBeange Yes, it should be OK, as long as `fg_rat_users` is part of the secondary groups of the Vob.

Comment: fg_rat_users is the vob owner. MMM confused.

Comment: @DBeange Vob owner? I thought fg_rat_users was a group?

Comment: sorry fg_rat_user is a group, (hope i've not confused) so when i describe the vob it shows vob ownership as owner vobadm & group fg_rat_user. The owning if vobadm is an admin account which is a member of both PG_RAT_USERS & FG_RAT_USERS

Comment: Hi, checking the vobrpc logs on client, view server & vob server there are no entries anywhere. The View ownership is the Clearcase Primary group. I did spot that the primary group Env Variable value was not defined with the domain qualifier so added that but it does not appeat to have made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "unable to transfer" is a key indication that the client application (cleartool.exe) and the view server process are using CCFS to get to the pools.

If this just started happening, please verify that your user account still maps to the unix server correctly. (...\clearcase\etc\utils\credmap server_name) @Vonc's lsview option will also tell you the view's user and group credentials, which can also be an issue -- particularly for CCFS transfers.

You may also want to see what happens on disabling CCFS on the client host and view server host (ClearCase control panel, options page). Be aware that this may merely change the nature of the failure if the albd account on Windows is not able to directly access the pools.

Comment: Hi, see answers above, but also when running credmap on the aix vobserver my primary group is "staff"  with additional group of "fg_rat_users" which is out version of ccusers. This is new set up of CC.

Comment: Still need the view information and whether you can disable CCFS and get things to work...

Comment: Hi Brain, sorry. disabling CCFS on client and view server made no difference

Comment: It should at least have changed the error message... If you still have a support contract with IBM, you may want to open a PMR. This is about to go down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Hi Brian. I've a PMR open but no luck so far. SAMBA all seems to be working, passwords in sync but still same error.

Comment: I see that you opened the PMR back on the 6th... Let me see what's happening.